# Mocha test failing for React component containing an image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, babeljs

I am doing unit tests for React components. The tests work fine, unless there is a component that contains an image. In that case case the component test never runs, because the program stops before the test even begins to run.

This is the directory structure

```
data
- images.js
public
- images
  - photo.jpeg
src
- components
  - Photo.js
test
- components
  - Photo.spec.js
package.json
```

This is the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "image-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "just an image",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=production mocha './test/**/*.spec.js' --require @babel/register"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.7",
    "@babel/helper-module-imports": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.7.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.7.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.7",
    "@babel/preset-es2015": "^7.0.0-beta.53",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/register": "^7.7.7",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.7.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "expect": "^24.9.0",
    "mocha": "^7.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.12.0"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the component `Photo.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

export default class Photo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { image } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
    <img
      src={require(`../../public/images/${image.display_src}`).default}
      alt={image.caption} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Photo.propTypes = {
  image: PropTypes.object,
}
```

Here is a data file which contains the information on one image (the actual implementation has more images).

```
const images = [
  {
    "display_src": "photo.jpeg",
    "caption": "The photo"
  },
]

export default images
```

Here is the component test file `Photo.spec.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import expect from 'expect'
import Photo from '../../src/components/Photo'

import images from '../../data/images'

describe('Photo Component', function () {
  it('should return a figure element', () => {
    const props = {
      image: images[0],
    }

    const result = TestRenderer.create(<Photo {...props} />)
    console.log(result)
    expect(result.type).toEqual('figure')
  })
})
```

When I run the test with

```
npm run test
```

I get this error:

```
/Users/elbegom/Desktop/study/redux/state-management/simpletest/public/images/photo.jpeg:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ����
```

Here is an image of the full output:

[Screenshot of Mocha test error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5eBy.png)

I also put a minimal test case on github [here](https://github.com/gellati/mocha-test-react-component-image)

Could someone say why the program fails? I also wonder how to fix this, and if this is the correct way to test a component with an image.

Comment: `require(someImage)` is not correct. Set the `.src` attribute to the image source directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require` function loads only Javascript files and it does not understand image format. If you want to render an image, you need to provide a direct URl to the src attribute

```
export default class Photo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { image } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <img src={`../../public/images/${image.display_src}`} alt={image.caption} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Also note that `src` path should be relative to the webpage url where the component is rendered, not to the javascript file location.

Comment: I should perhaps have included in my question that I use Webpack as a bundler, and the `require` function is for Webpack to be able to load the images and other static assets (since `import` cannot be used inside the component). At the time of writing I thought the issue was with Babel. I was able to solve the issue by setting the source URI in the component state during `componentDidMount`, and now images display normally and I can also write at least some tests. But the given answer is fine for the question i had.